# ngModel not updated with input value angular 2 test karma

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a problem during my units test with angular 2. I just want to test an input to check if my model can't be more than 16 chars. (I have indeed use a maxlength in my html). So I enter a new value in my input and use dispatchEvent to set the input in the model but the model is nether update...

Here is my test :

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import { EditRequestComponent } from './edit-request.component';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }           from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { __platform_browser_private__ as _ } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { MvpSelector } from './mvpSelector/mvpSelector.component';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpModule, Http, BaseRequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryWebApiService } from '../../services/in-memory.service';
import { MyDatePickerModule } from 'mydatepicker/dist/my-date-picker.module';
import { ReferentialService, RequestService, ConfigurationService } from '../../services';
import { MvpRequestClass } from '../../models';

////////  SPECS  /////////////
describe('EditRequestComponent', function () {
  let comp: EditRequestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EditRequestComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ 
        ReferentialService, 
        ConfigurationService,
        RequestService, 
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions) => {
              return new Http(backend, options);
          },
          deps: [ MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions ]
        },
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            snapshot: {
              params: {id: 1},
              data: {request: new MvpRequestClass()}
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      declarations: [ MvpSelector, EditRequestComponent ],
      imports: [ FormsModule, FormsModule, MyDatePickerModule,
                  HttpModule ]
    }).compileComponents();
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditRequestComponent);
      comp = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create component', () => expect(comp).toBeDefined() );

  it('should have a mvpRequestComponent', () =>
  {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(comp.mvpReq).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should not have more than 16 char in moInCharge input', fakeAsync(() => {
    comp.mvpReq.moInCharge = "oldValue";
    fixture.detectChanges();

    var field = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.input-moInCharge')).nativeElement;
    field.value = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    _.getDOM().dispatchEvent(field, _.getDOM().createEvent("input"));

    tick();
    console.log(field.value);
    expect(comp.mvpReq.moInCharge.length).toBeLessThanOrEqual(16);
  }));

});
```

Here are the Log print in my console:

```
LOG LOG: 'oldValue'
```

You can also see that I have a weird way to use dispatchEvent. That's because when I import and use it directly from '@angular/platform-browser/testing/browser_util' I have an error message :

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
  at webpack:///~/@angular/platform-browser/testing/browser_util.js:8:0 <- karma.entry.js:49907
```

It seems that there was imports directly in the file browser_util.d.ts that our webpack doesn't appreciate. But the dispatchEvent function is sensibly used the same way. So I don't understand why the model doesn't update.

Here are few test that I made to make it work:

- use async() function rather than fakeAsync
- use the dispatchEvent function of MDN
- use fixture.whenStable() with a then()
- change the number of 'a' to check if the value doesn't update because
  there are too many
- a combination of all this points

And that's all. I must admit that I don't know how to proceed differently to make it work. If you can help me or you want more details, don't hesitate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to put an async() in your first beforeEach()? and you won't need fakeAsync/async & tick in your it() block, just put your expect() in fixture.whenStable().then().. that worked for me at least - hope it helps :)